# JDBCTemplate not handling Unicode characters from DB

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I am trying to read from DB which contains unicode characters.

When I query directly with `CHARACTER SET utf8`, it works fine.

But, when I used JDBCTemplate, even with `characterEncoding` in the mysql URL, it still gives different output.

From MYSQL (Expected) in HEX: `0xc2 0x9`

From JDBCTemplate (Actual) in HEX: `0xef 0xbf 0xb`

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the character data you're expecting. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Updated question.

Comment: Your update doesn't specify the characters, those are just bytes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Those characters are non printable.